# Automatically create collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

is it possible to update this method:

```
void uploadMatch(team1, team2) {
    Firestore.instance.collection("upcomings").add({
      "createdAt": Timestamp.now(),
      "upcomingTeam1": team1,
      "upcomingTeam2": team2
    });
  }
```

so that if the upcomings collection doesn't exist, it creates it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> Collections and documents are created implicitly in Cloud Firestore.
> Simply assign data to a document within a collection. If either the
> collection or document does not exist, Cloud Firestore creates it.

So to answer your question: It's not possible! **The collection is created implicitly** when you create a document and when you delete the last document in a collection, it will cease to exist.